# How to fix the following unexpected clipping path?

Tags: pstricks

I want to shade as follows.

[image]

However, my code below produces an unexpected result as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-1,-1)(11,11)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,-45,45,135,180,90}]
        (0,0){A}
        (10,0){B}
        (10,10){C}
        (0,10){D}
        (0,5){M}
        (5,10){N}
    \psframe(10,10)
    \psarcn(A){10}{90}{0}
    \psarcn(M){5}{90}{-90}
    \psarcn(N){5}{0}{180}
    \pstInterCC[RadiusA=\pstDistVal{10},RadiusB=\pstDistVal{5}]{A}{}{N}{}{P1}{P2}
    \pstInterCC[RadiusA=\pstDistVal{5},RadiusB=\pstDistVal{5}]{M}{}{N}{}{P3}{P4}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]
    {
        \psarcn[origin=M](M){5}{(D)}{(P4)}
        \psarc[origin=N](N){5}{(P4)}{(P2)}
        \psarc[origin=O](O){10}{(P2)}{(D)}
        \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Question

I can not find the culprit, can you?

Comment: That should be done with clipping and not finding the intersections ...

Comment: @user187802: Is clipping the general solution for any cases? If it is correct then I always have to put clipping as the first resort.

Comment: For all areas which borders are build by functions or data sets. However, if the filled area is only build by one or two functions and the axes of the coordinate system, then a simple `\pscustom` may be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the pst-eucl syntax for the custom curve. Note that, probably due to approximating errors, I had to plot the half-circles twice.

```
\documentclass[pstricks, svgnames, border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-1,-1)(11,11)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,-45,45,135,180,90}]
        (0,0){A}
        (10,0){B}
        (10,10){C}
        (0,10){D}
        (0,5){M}
        (5,10){N}
    \psframe(10,10)
    \psarcn(A){10}{90}{0}
    \psarcn(M){5}{90}{-90}
    \psarcn(N){5}{0}{180}
    \pstInterCC[RadiusA=\pstDistVal{10},RadiusB=\pstDistVal{5}]{A}{}{N}{}{D}{P2}%D = P1
    \pstInterCC[RadiusA=\pstDistVal{5},RadiusB=\pstDistVal{5}]{M}{}{N}{}{D}{P4}% D = P3
     \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Silver!40!Lavender, linestyle=none]
     {
     \pstArcnOAB{M}{D}{P4}
     \pstArcOAB{N}{P4}{P2}
     \pstArcOAB{A}{P2}{D}
     \closepath
        }
    \psarcn(A){10}{90}{0}
    \psarcn(M){5}{90}{-90}
    \psarcn(N){5}{0}{180}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you remove the `linestyle=none` then you don't need to restroke the semi-circles .

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer: That's how I coded first, but there was a very small difference on zooming, which I interpret as a very small error in the intersection coordinates computation.

Comment: Which point on zooming did you notice the small difference? I don't see any such a difference.

Comment: On the image posted, you won't see any, since I redrew the semi-circles. There's a tiny difference for the middle arc (the basis of the curvilinear triangle, so to say). I even tried to play with `dimen=inner` or `outer`, but it didn't change much.